# Using deploy time parameters in CDK 'codepipeline_actions.CloudFormationCreateUpdateStackAction'

Tags: parameters, aws-cloudformation, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild, dynamicparameters

I am clearly not understanding how dynamic parameters can be used when deploying a template in CodePipeline.  Here is the basic scenario:

CodeBuild BUILD Action - Here I have retrieved, for instance, a value for COMMIT_NUMBER.  This can be set as an environment variable, or saved to a file... whatever needs to be done. In a post_build step I package up the template using "sam package ...."

CloudFormation DEPLOY stage - Here I use

```
new codepipeline_actions.CloudFormationCreateUpdateStackAction({
      actionName: `The_Deploy`,
      templatePath: buildOutput.atPath(TEMPLATE_FILE_NAME),
      parameterOverrides, --These are known when I synth the pipeline
      stackName: envStackName,
      cfnCapabilities: [CfnCapabilities.AUTO_EXPAND, CfnCapabilities.ANONYMOUS_IAM],
      adminPermissions: true,
      role: buildRole,
      runOrder: runOrder || 1
    });
```

to deploy the template that was packaged up. In the props for this method, there is a parameterOverrides property, but anything in there would have to be known at build time.

My question is HOW do i set dynamic parameter values that are known in the build step, to the parameters consumed by the deploy step.

Thanks for any clarification!

Comment: https://wrzasq.pl/blog/variables-namespaces-in-codepipeline-for-multi-stage-deployment-pipelines.html - good explanation of namespace variables there which is what you need, potentially also https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/build-spec-ref.html#build-spec.env.exported-variables and https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/build-env-ref-env-vars.html

Comment: THANK you for the very informative link... there was a key sentence that brought it all together... for me at least.  I did a write-up below, with the solution that I have tested and works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you @Ronan Cunningham, for the link : [here](https://wrzasq.pl/blog/variables-namespaces-in-codepipeline-for-multi-stage-deployment-pipelines.html).  The KEY point that clarified how to do this was this sentence below, that I have not found explained well otherwise:

> "Since namespaces are native CodePipeline feature, they are not
> restricted only to CloudFormation actions. Now you can for example
> define CodeBuild environment variables in a dynamic way as well (it is
> also possible to define export variables in CodeBuild - these values
> will will become step output values):" ....

To bring it all together here are the key pieces that allowed me to set an environment variable in the codebuild action and pass it to a cloudformation parameter IN CDK:

1.) add env variable and export variable in the build project

```
const buildProject = new codebuild.PipelineProject(construct, `buildProject`, {
    buildSpec: codebuild.BuildSpec.fromObject({
    version: '0.2',
    env: {
      "variables": {
        "MY_IMPORTANT_INFO": "some-default-value-here"
      },
      "exported-variables": [ "MY_IMPORTANT_INFO" ]
    },
    phases: {
      install: {...},
      build: {
        commands: [ NOTE... variable above can be changed here...]
      }
    },
    artifacts: {...}
    role: buildRole
  })
```

2.) Add namespace to the build action:

```
new codepipeline_actions.CodeBuildAction({
      actionName: `The_Build`,
      project: buildProject,
      input: sourceOutput,
      outputs: [buildOutput],
      role: buildRole,
      variablesNamespace: 'build'
    })
```

3.) In the deployment stage, I can now set the ParameterOverride by setting the parameter name to the environment variable that was exported in the build step:

```
new codepipeline_actions.CloudFormationCreateUpdateStackAction({
      actionName: `The_Deploy`,
      templatePath: buildOutput.atPath(TEMPLATE_FILE_NAME),
      parameterOverrides: [
        {"COMMIT_NUMBER": "#{build.MY_IMPORTANT_INFO}"}
      ],
      stackName: envStackName,
      cfnCapabilities: [CfnCapabilities.AUTO_EXPAND, CfnCapabilities.ANONYMOUS_IAM],
      adminPermissions: true,
      role: buildRole,
      runOrder: runOrder || 1
    });
```

Hallelujah!

And, thanks again to Ronan for the informative link!

Comment: Brilliant that you got it working.